# Performance: List containing lots of objects VS lots of objects containing smaller lists

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, history, revert

I am currently developing my own app (just another remake of the famous "Game of Life") and I want to add a "revert" button. My game basically consists of a two dimensional array: Cell[][]...
So: My idea was to create an ArrayList which that array is being added to every update... (With a limit of 50 entries)
But then I thought, that that would be a lot of Objects in that list... So:

Would it be more performant to have an ArrayList in each cell in the 2-dimensional array, containing the history of itself, or to have a huge ArrayList containing entire game states as a history?

(I don't think you need any of my code to answer this question, but I will post it if you do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing cell *state*, why not keep the *events* that transform the cell state? An event would simply encapsulate the previous state info and the next state, or maybe even a coding enum that can be executed in reverse. This would already significantly reduce the data you need to store.

Also, it makes a difference if you're working natively, or on a garbage-collecting VM platform such as Java or C#. The former tends to be faster and is more forgiving in terms of large addressing storage, while the latter can start trashing wildly if you store lots of objects.

But the real proof of the pudding is in the eating / tinstatfc: there is no such thing as the fastest code (c) Michael Abrash -> i.e. benchmark your code and find out! (and come tell us)

Comment: How would I store events? Firstly: I don't have any events, but I could create some...
Secondly: If I wanted to store them, wouldn't that be pretty much the same as storing the states?

Comment: An array list with the state of a single cell is just a list of booleans, so I don't think a list of events would be less data

Comment: To answer your second question: if all your cells constantly change, yes but that is not necessarily the case. It depends a bit on how 'rich' your conversion rules and state data are. For example in the basic version of the game, a number of famous patterns often simply repeats over a number of frames with fixed movements. This can also be exploited to save space.

Comment: Oh yes that sounds smart! But still: lets say I wouldn't put the states into the list, but instead, i would just add a true if the state changed, and a false if it didn't... It would still be the same amount of booleans wouldn't it?

Comment: Ex: If on average just 20 cells change in a 50x50 field each frame, you spend less than 1% of memory per frame when storing the changing cells only, as opposed to storing 2500 cells of state per frame. Alternatively, you can also subdivide the board in blocks and use the bits in a hash function so that you can store each block as a string. You could even use a dictionary to refer to blocks that have already been active earlier.

Comment: "you spend less than 1% of memory per frame when storing the changing cells only, as opposed to storing 2500 cells of state per frame." How exactly do you mean "storing" booleans in an array? Something else in something else? :D

Comment: Instead of booleans you can store coordinates that mark flipped cells. Unless you use packed bit-fields or bit-strings, booleans are stored as bytes, so storing a coordinate is not very much more expensive vs. storing a 'boolean'.

Comment: So you would store Integers (or float/...) for the coordinates of the flippen cells in ArrayLists for all the frames in a big ArrayList for the entire history...
Correct?

Comment: Indeed, store the coordinates of flipped cells in an ArrayList (1frame), store each of these frames in another ArrayList (or Stack or Deque..)

Comment: Ok, I just gave every cell an ArrayList containing booleans representing its state... Maybe it's not the most performant method, but it is the easiest and it works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, an `ArrayList` per cell would work fine; however, if you only want to store 50 states, you'll have to create a custom ADT or utilize Guava's Collections API.

I recommend using a `Stack` rather than an `ArrayList`, as reverting every cell would be a simple operation.  In Java, the correct ADT to use is an `ArrayDeque`, but you'll have to handle capacity yourself.

Comment: I thought of just removing the oldest state if the newest one will be the 50th (100th/...) one... Or are there any REAL advantages when using stacks? I've never used them bevore

Comment: Using a `Stack` would just be easier to use, and an `ArrayDeque` allows you to edit both sides of the collection, meaning you can add a new element and remove the oldest simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, I just gave every cell an ArrayList containing booleans representing its state... Maybe it's not the most performant method, but it is the easiest and it works like a charm